# Angular $resource - attach a generic .finally function to a method

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I have a generic restful resource with angular's $resource.  On any save method, I also want to set a message and boolean on whatever scope I'm in, and set a timeout for that message.  So anywhere in my code where I call .save/.$save, I then attach a .finally onto it (below).

Rather than putting the same .finally onto every save I call, I'm wondering if I can just write a finally onto the actual resource itself, and have this be a generic finally for my save function.

---

```
var resource = $resource(
  pageListPath, 
  {}, 
  {
    query: {method:'GET', isArray:true},
    get: {method:'GET', url: pageDetailPath, params:{id:'@id'}, cache:true},
    save: {method:'PUT', url: pageSavePath, params:{id:'@id'}},
    delete: {method:'DELETE', url: pageDetailPath, params:{id:'@id'}}
  }
);

return resource;
```

---

```
    .finally(function() {
      $scope.loading = false;
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.message = false;
      }, 2500);
    });
```

---

Ideally something like

```
save: {
  method:'PUT', 
  url:pageSavePath, 
  params:{id:'@id'}, 
  finally:function() { doStuff() }}
```

is what I'm looking for.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing another service to encapsulate this one, providing generic functionality for certain responses.

The API service:

```
pageServices.factory('PageAPI',
  ['$resource', 
  function($resource,
    var resource = $resource(
      pageListPath, 
      {}, 
      {
        query: {
          method:'GET', 
          isArray:true
        },
        get: {
          method:'GET', 
          url: pageDetailPath, 
          params:{ id:'@id' }
        },
        ...,
        ...,
     }
    );

  return resource;

  }]
);

pageServices.factory('Page', ['PageAPI',
  function(PageAPI) {
    var service = {
      'getPages': function() {
        return PageAPI.query(function(response) {
          // Do stuff with success
        }, function(err) {
          // Handle error
        }).$promise.finally(function() {
          // Generic finally handler
        }
      },
      ...,
      ...,
    }
    return service
  }
])
```